# Coded UI Test Fails to find Wpf Popup Window controls

Tags: automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automate a ribbon control in power point. In that ribbon there are popup windows which contains settings information, when I try to automation those setting popup windows using Coded UI, I got error message like "the control cannot be located playback fail to find control with give search properties", But Coded UI can find the popup window but it fails to find any controls inside it.I have already tried with

```
SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch and setfocus()
```

Does any one have solutions, it will be very helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent object, i.e the popup window, and enumerate through the children objects manually if codedUI is not able to locate the objects.

```
IEnumerator<UITestControl> appt = uiMainWindowControl.GetChildren().GetEnumerator();
```